# Button OnClick() is not working in one click. It takes two clicks to do a function in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, onclick, next.js

I working a react project

I am doing a stepper, In the final step I have a Rest button.

```
<Button onClick={handleReset} variant="contained">
            Reset
          </Button>
```

Inside the `handleReset()` function I do

```
  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);   // This is a state to set the active step as step-0
    router.push('/booking');  // I am in another route. I have to come this URL
  };
```

When I clicking the button,
When the first click
The URL is changing to `http://localhost:3000/booking`
And, The second click the stepper goes to step-0.

When I could not do both actions in my first click? Why I need to click two times?

Anybody has faced this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by 
// I am in another route. I have to come this URL

Comment: You want to change the state of current page route and then change to /book route ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you posted. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @Rakesh I mean, Before clicking the Rest button, The url is http://localhost:3000/booking ?&status= success. When I click Reset button the url has to change tohttp://localhost:3000/booking . Sorry for the late reply